# Delete specific value from Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to delete a specific item from 'Session'.
My code is:

```
public ActionResult DeleteProductFromCart(AddToCart id)
{
MyDBContext myDBContext = new MyDBContext();
List<AddToCart> cart = (List<AddToCart>)Session["cart"];
cart.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt16(cart.Contains(id)));      
return RedirectToAction("ViewCart");
}
```

But this is not working properly.

Comment: You are calling `cart.RemoveAt()` passing in `cart.Contains(id)` which looks like a boolean. So you aren't really trying to remove a value from a session. Where does this code come from?

Comment: could you please show your `AddToCart` class?

Comment: @reckface i wrote it myself. if id=4, this code is removing value from index 4 not the product having id=4

Answer (score 1):

`cart.Contains(id)` will return a boolean, not the index of the item that you want to remove.

You will need to make some adjustments similar to the following code(assuming that your `AddToCart` class has an Id field):

1- rename your passed parameter for better readability

```
public ActionResult DeleteProductFromCart(AddToCart item)
```

2- get the item (if it does exist in your collection):

```
var itemToBeRemoved = cart.SingleOrDefault(i=>i.Id == item.Id);

// if the item exists, remove it from the cart collection
if(itemToBeRemoved!=null)
{
   cart.remove(itemToBeRemoved);
}
```

Comment: @BilalMustafa: welcome. Kindly don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if this has fixed your problem :)

Comment: @mukeshkudi: no worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an id property in `AddToCart` Class

1. First you have to retrieve carts from session

   ```
   List<AddToCart> cart = (List<AddToCart>)Session["cart"];
   ```
2. After that you have to get cart associated with id

   ```
   AddToCart itemToDelete=cart.FirstorDefault(x=>x.id==id.id);
   ```
3. Finally you can delete like this...

   ```
   cart.Remove(itemToDelete);
   ```

Comment: `x=>x.id==id` will fail since you need to get the `id` from the passed `AddToCart` object. something like that should work: `x=>x.id==passedItem.id`